# Downgrade from .NET 4 to 3.5 - The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System'

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, runtimeexception

I've just been asked to downgrade an application from .NET 4.0 to .NET 3.5 for compatibility on a customer's server.  The application compiled successfully, however it loads a C# source file and complies it at runtime to allow the customer to change the functionality.

In the application it is throwing an exception when it tries to compile the source file as it can't find System.Linq.  I've tried to add System.Data.Linq.dll as a compile reference and it states System.Data.Linq.dll could not be found. I've tried adding mscorlib.dll as a compile reference as that was a hint from another post, but that was to no avail.

Any suggestions?

I've included the following references within my project and I've tried passing them through to the compiler.

System.dll, System.Core.dll, System.Data.dll, System.Data.Linq.dll, System.Drawing.dll, System.Xml.dll

Comment: System.Core.dll should be all you need, at least for LINQ to Objects. Double check that you really, really are loading that.

Comment: How do you add your referenced assemblies to the compiler? Make sure, these are taken in the correct (ie 3.5 not 4 or higher) version..

Comment: In the end I removed the Linq from the script as the customer has not modified and it was only using a single Any().  Plus it was an unpaid change, so I don't want to spent lot of time!